# how to send a post request with SplashRequest in scrapy_splash

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I try to use SplashRequest with endpoint='execute' with below code to send a post request,but the result shows I didn't succeed.

```
import re
import sys
import os
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from crawler.items import CrawlerItem


class Exp10itSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    lua_script = """
    function main(splash, args)
      assert(splash:go(args.url))
      assert(splash:wait(0.5))
      return splash:html()
    end
    """

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://httpbin.org/post^sss=lalala'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            if "^" in url:
                post_url_list = url.split("^")
                post_url = post_url_list[0]
                post_data = post_url_list[1]
                yield SplashRequest(post_url, self.parse, endpoint='execute', magic_response=True, meta={'handle_httpstatus_all': True}, args={'lua_source': self.lua_script, 'http_method': 'POST', 'body': post_data})

    def parse(self, response):
        input("body is:")
        print(response.body)
```

However,I can not post it successully,the return content shows me I don't post it well.Can you help me on post request with SplashRequest in scrapy_splash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash):

> Splash 1.8+ is required to handle POST requests; in earlier Splash versions `http_method` and `body` arguments are ignored. If you work with `/execute` endpoint and want to support POST requests you have to handle `http_method` and `body` arguments in your Lua script manually.

Also in the documentation, there's an example of POST request. Adapted for a minimal ready-to-run example:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class SplashPostSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "splash_post"

    lua_script = """
    function main(splash, args)
      assert(splash:go{
        splash.args.url,
        http_method=splash.args.http_method,
        body=splash.args.body,
      })
      assert(splash:wait(0.5))
      return {
        html = splash:html(),
      }
    end
    """

    def start_requests(self):
        post_url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
        post_data = 'foo=bar'
        yield SplashRequest(post_url, self.parse, endpoint='execute',
                            magic_response=True, meta={'handle_httpstatus_all': True},
                            args={'lua_source': self.lua_script, 'http_method': 'POST', 'body': post_data})

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.body)
```